# Timeline SmartArt in PowerPoint

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint

In the PowerPoint 365 template Artistic Neon on slide two there is a timeline called Rounded Rectangle Timeline. I want to create a new one on a blank PowerPoint presentation, but can not find where this SmartArt timeline is and how to insert it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on my test, there is no such timeline in SmartArt graphics. It seems to be achieved via "Design Ideas" feature.

More detailed information and requirements about this feature, please refer to "[Create professional slide layouts with PowerPoint Designer](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/create-professional-slide-layouts-with-powerpoint-designer-53c77d7b-dc40-45c2-b684-81415eac0617?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US)".

[image]

If needed, you may delete other slides and save the file with timeline as a template file(.potx). Generally, the templates would be save into Default personal templates location.
Next time you need to create a timeline, you may go to New > Personal > choose this template.